# Mongodb db design - single or multiple collections?

Tags: mongodb, database-design

I'm new to the Mongodb approach to db design. I have users who can add **Channels** and **Links** where each Channel will potentially have many Links. Links will also be visited many times and therefore I need to store **Visits** too.

Specific links will need to be found at times as well as all links belonging to a specific channel. I would also need to be able to find all visits to a particular link regularly. Could someone tell me how they would design the db in this case?

I'm thinking of separate collections for each as I assume this would be more efficient for searching but I'm not entirely convinced this thinking is accurate.

Comment: Where do you see the advantage of using a document store like mongodb for this scenario?

Comment: Fair point - it's partly a learning exercise for me though. Do you think the requirements are beyond/inappropriate for Mongodb?

Comment: It depends on your usage patterns for the data. For an experiment I'd go with just two collections, one for the users, one containing channels->links->visits The problem with using three separate collections is searching as there's no join.

Comment: actually I didn't mention users because they are stored by a 3rd party. I guess I could just store the id of the channel with each link  but I realise this will result in more calls to the db I'm sure

Comment: Take a look at: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/data-models/

Comment: can you elaborate on the details of "I would also need to be able to find all visits to a particular link" - and visits in general: do you need to track visits by separate users separately?

Answer (score 1):

take a look at the link James had provided.  but aside from that, its all about the details.  Its tempting to store links in the channels -- one collection.  But, if you say each channel can have many links -- is that unbounded growth? if so, then you have to have separate collections where each channel references multiple links in another collection.  Similar logic applies to Links and Visits (unless Visits is just a count?).   You can also try to do a "hybrid" approach -- a channel will embed just a few links so they are retrieved "in one shot" with the channel, and the rest of the links are referenced

Comment: thanks for this, very useful - the links in each channel are unbound but there would never be that many so I could embed them. However, 3rd parties will be searching for links (where channels aren't relevant) and so I thought a separate collection for the links would be more efficient.

Comment: Visits is not just a count and this is unbound with potential to increase massively. So it looks like 3 collections but when I want to find all the channels and a count for the number of links within each channel I will need to make two calls to the db!